# Getting 2 errors with a JavaScript Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, object, timer, null

I have created a countdown timer which counts down to 5pm every day then resets to 5pm the following day.

The timer works perfectly, but I am getting 2 errors from the code which I am Struggling to solve.

The code is below:

```
    function startTimer(display) {
    var date = new Date();
    var h17 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 17);
    if(date.getHours() >= 17) {
        h17.setDate(h17.getDate()+1);
    }
    h17 = h17.getTime();
    var diff,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds;

    function timer() {
        diff = (((h17 - Date.now()) / 1000) | 0);

        // Setting and displaying hours, minutes, seconds
        hours = (diff / 3600) | 0;
        minutes = ((diff % 3600) / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    };
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
window.onload = function () {
    var display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(display);
};
```

The errors are looking like line 14: `diff = (((h17 - Date.now()) / 1000) | 0);`

Returning the message : "Object doesn't support this property or method: line 14"

and line 25: `display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;`

Returning the message "Cannot set property 'textContent' of null".

Comment: Which browser are you using? You can use a polyfill for `Date.now` as `if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}` It works fine for me. tested in chrome browser http://jsfiddle.net/wussvqag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was coming from binding the output to the #time ID in the html.

Since I had put the script in the  and only used this on certain pages, the error was coming from the pages where there was no `<div id="time">`, so the display was null.

I have fixed this by checking if the element ID exists before running the script.

```
if(document.getElementById("time")){
        var display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(display);
    } else {

    }
```